# I need support about Oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm working with Oracle.
How to take the name of columns in the table.
I can it, please help me.I use this code but not success

```
Select Column_name
From Information_schema.columns
Where table_name = 'Student';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Information_schema` sounds like MySQL. This won't work in Oracle. The views to use are either `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`, `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`, or `DBA_TAB_COLS`.

Best of luck.